# Calculating MLE for unknown parameters

Tags: probability, statistics, maximum-likelihood

Given a random variable $X$, assume it takes on the values $\{1,2,3\}$ with probabilities $Pr[X=1] = p_1$, $Pr[X=2] = 2p_1$, and $Pr[X=3] = p_2$. $p_1$ and $p_2$ are unknown parameters we must calculate using MLE. We also have observations $D = \{x_1, \cdots, x_n \}$ that are iid from $X$.

First, we must ensure that $Pr[X=i]$ is a valid probability mass function. For it to be valid, $3p_1$ + $p_2$ must add up to $1$. Additionally, $p_1 \ge 0$ and $p_2 \ge 0$.

To calculate $\hat{p}$ using MLE, we must first derive the joint probability $Pr[D; p]$ and the log probability $\log Pr[D; p]$. First, the joint probability $Pr[D; p] = p_1^{n_1} (2p_1)^{n_2} (p_2)^{n_3}$ where $n$ represents the number of observations in $D$. The log probability $\log Pr[D;p] = n_1\log p_1 + n_2\log 2p_1 + n_3\log p_2$.

From here, I am unsure how to calculate $\hat{p_1}$ and $\hat{p_2}$ since there are two parameters in $\log Pr[D;p]$. I tried solving for both $p_1$ and $p_2$, but each variable shows up in the closed form solution of other, which I don't believe is a correct formulation.

Edit: Based on the comments, here is what I have tried (for p_1):
$$\nabla \log Pr[D;p] = \frac{n_1 + n_2}{p_1} + \frac{n_3}{1 - 3p_2} = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow (1-3p_1)(n_1+n_2) = -p_1n_3$$
$$\Rightarrow p_1 = \frac{n_1 + n_2}{3n_1 + n_2 - n_3}$$

Comment: You should try substituting $p_2$ with $1 - 3p_1$ so that your log probability is in terms of a single parameter.

Comment: As you say $p_2+3p_1=1$ so doesn't mean that $p_2=1-3p_1$ so you have only one unknown parameter? Furthermore $D\sim Multinomial$ with $p_1=p,p_2=2p,p_3=1-3p$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Can you take a look at my edit and see if that is the right approach to solving for $p_1$? If so, I will go ahead and do the same for $p_2$.

Comment: Your approach looks correct. But you should mention that $n_1+n_2+n_3=n$ when you write the likelihood function. And define what $n_i$ means of course.

Comment: Isn't $(log(1-3p))'=\frac{1}{1-3p}\cdot (-3)$ and in order to find $p_2$ you have just to solve $p_2=1-3p$ with $p$ the one you have already found.

Comment: Thanks for the catch @papasmurfete. I got $p_1 = \frac{n_1+n_2}{3(n_1+n_2-n_3)}$ and $p_2 = \frac{-n_3}{n_1+n_2-n_3}$. Does this seem correct?

Comment: If Im not mistaken $p_1=\frac{n_1+n_2}{3(n_1+n_2+n_3)}$ and so as  StubbornAtom said $p_1=\frac{n_1+n_2}{3n}$ and so $p_2=1-3\frac{n_1+n_2}{3n}=\frac{n_3}{n}$